# Materialize Css datePicker works for the first-time. When I choose the same Picker the next time The picker comes and goes

Tags: materialize

My materialize DatePicker works only for the FirstTime

I am using Materialize for devloping a site which invloves date-picker. The date-picker works only for the first load of a page. When we select the date for second-time it comes and goes.

How to solve this type of problem? Any help is greately Appriciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--=============== basic  ===============-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
     <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->



<script type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <style>

      h5{
       font-size: 1.875rem;
       line-height: 2.5rem;
       letter-spacing: .5px;
       color: #98AAB8;
    margin-right: -.5px; font-weight:700; font-family: Neue Plak,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;
      }
      input {
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 10px 9px 10px 47px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #2F3B59;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 13px; 
}
     .input_field1{
        line-height: normal;
    padding: 12px 9px 12px 47px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #2F3B59;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    width:100%;
    font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
.text_area{
    padding:69px 280px;
}
.input_date{
        line-height: normal;
    padding: 13px 9px 10px 47px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #2F3B59;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
.form_header {
    font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    /* float: left; */
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:#666;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.posterImg{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0;
    width: 164px;
    height: 159px;
    padding: 55px 2px 11px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #2F3B59;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #98AAB8;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.breadcrumb:before {
    content: '\E5CC';
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #566985;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 8px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.card .card-action a:not(.btn):not(.btn-large):not(.btn-small):not(.btn-large):not(.btn-floating) {
    /* color: #ffab40; */
    color: #566985;}

    textarea.materialize-textarea {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    border: none;
    border: 1px solid #2F3B59;
    padding: .8rem 0 1.6rem 0;
    resize: none;
    min-height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

input[type=text]:not(.browser-default){
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #9e9e9e; */
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;

}

  </style>
      <!-- Fav icon -->
</head>
        <div class="navbar-fixed">
            <nav>
              <div class="nav-wrapper" style="background: #2F3B59;">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                  <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div style="height:30px; background:white;"></div>
          </div>
             <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m1"></div>
                    <div class="col s12 m10">
                        <nav style="border: 1px solid #eee;background: #F8FBFE; border-radius:5px;">

                            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                              <div class="col s12">
                                    <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb" style="color: #566985" style="float:left;">Add Listing</a>
                                <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb" style="color:#566985;float: right">Add conference</a>
                                <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb"style="color: #566985;float: right">Profile</a>
                                <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb" style="color: #566985;float: right">Home</a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m1"></div>
            </div>     


            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m1"></div>
                <div class="col s12 m3">
                        <div class="card sticky-action" style="border: 1px solid #eee;">
                       <div class="card-action">
                            <div class="card" style="background: #F8FBFE; border-radius:5px;border: 1px solid #eee;">

                                    <div class="card-action">
                                     <a href="#" style="text-transform: none;color:#50596E; font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif; font-size:13px;font-weight:600">Edit Profile</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-action">
                                     <a href="#"  style="text-transform: none;color:#50596E;font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif; font-size:13px;font-weight:600">Add event</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-action">
                                     <a href="#"  style="text-transform: none; color:#50596E;font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif; font-size:13px;font-weight:600 ">Added Events</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-action">
                                  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" style="background: #4DB7FE; color: #566985;">Save</a> 
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                       </div>

                        <div class="card-reveal"> <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>


                <div class="col s12 m7">
                    <h5 style="text-align:center;font-family: quick-sand, sans-serif;">Conference Details</h5>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                            <div class="form_header">Conference Link</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-link"></i><input type=""  class="input_field1"  placeholder="Conference Link" autocomplete="off">

                            </div>

                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Conference Name</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i><input type="" class="input_field1" placeholder="Conference Name" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Conference URL</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-link"></i> <input type="" class="input_field1"  placeholder="Conference URL">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Conference Registration URL</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> <input type="" class="input_field1"  placeholder="Conference Registration URL">
                     </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                           <div class="form_header">Conference Start Date</div>
                           <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i><input  type="" class="input_date" id="datepicker1"  placeholder="yyy-mm-dd" onclick="jithendra()">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                           <div class="form_header">Conference End Date</div>
                           <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i><input type="" class="input_date" id="datepicker2"  placeholder="yyy-mm-dd" onclick="jithendra1()">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Twitter Handle</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><input type="" class="input_field1"  placeholder="City">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                           <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin-top:30px;"></div>
                     </div>


                     <div class="col s12 m4">

                     </div>

                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header" style="margin-top:20px;">City</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>  <input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="City">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Venue</div>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="Venue">

                     </div>
                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header" style="width: 338px;">Keywords</div>
                          <input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="Keywords">

                     </div>

                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div class="form_header">Conference City</div>

                          <input  type="file" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="Venue" style="opacity:0px;">

                     </div>

                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top: 21px;"></div>
                      </div>


                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                      </div>



                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="background: #2F3B59;border-radius:5px;">Submmit</a>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin-top:30px;"></div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin-top:30px;"></div>
                      </div>


                   <!-- <div class="col s12 m4">
                      <div class="form_header" >Poster Image</div>
                      <div class="input" style="border:none;border: 1px solid #2F3B59;;height: 180px;border-radius: 5px;background: #f9f9f9;/* padding-bottom: 16px; */">
                        <input type="text"></div>
                      <input type="file" class="input_field1" style="height: 180px;
                      opacity: -0.7;
                      position: absolute;
                      width: 146px;
                      margin-top: -180px;">

                  </div>
                  <div class="col s12 m3"></div>

                   <div class="col s12 m4">
                        <div class="form_header" >Card Image</div>
                        <div class="input" style="border:none;border: 1px solid #2F3B59;height: 180px;border-radius: 5px;background: #f9f9f9;/* padding-bottom: 16px; */">
                          <input type="text"></div>
                        <input type="file" class="input_field1" style="height: 180px;
                        opacity: -0.7;
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 146px;
                        margin-top: -180px;">
                    </div> -->

<!-- 

                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                     <hr>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <h5>My Socials</h5>
                            </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div class="form_header">Facebook </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="https://facebook.com/">

                 </div>
                 <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div class="form_header">LinkedIn </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i><input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="Linkedin.com">

                 </div>
                 <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div class="form_header">Twitter </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><input  type="" class="input_field1" type="text" placeholder="https://twitter.com/">

                 </div>
                </div> -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>




            <footer class="page-footer" style="background: #2F3B59;">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m3">
                      <h5 class="white-text">KonfHub</h5>
                      <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m3">
                      <h5 class="white-text">Link</h5>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 m3">
                            <h5 class="white-text">Link</h5>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                              <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                              <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                              <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s12 m3">
                                <h5 class="white-text">Link</h5>
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <div class="footer-copyright">
                  <div class="container">
                  © 2014 Copyright Text
                  <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        <script>


function jithendra(){  
  $('.modal').modal();
$('#datepicker1').pickadate({

selectMonths: true,// Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,

});
}
function jithendra1(){
 $('#datepicker2').pickadate({
selectMonths: true,// Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
});
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's there in "js/script.js", I think you should provide a link of codepen. So, it'll be easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jithendraathipatla/pen/ydawOw


Please help me Out!! When I click on the datePicker It works well for the first time, If I click on the same input it dose not work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things in your code. You were using both the versions of Materialize 1.0.0 and 0.100.2, no idea why you should use only one version and then I updated the `jQuery` methods as per the new version that is 1.0.0, you can check those on their website [Picker - Materialize](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html) and [Select - Materialize](https://materializecss.com/select.html). You were using `.input-date` class but in order to use `datepicker` you've to use `.datepicker` class only, you can modify the CSS of `.datepicker` class. I added `!important` to the changes you've made to the `.datepicker` class, so you can have the modified CSS which you applied to `.input-date`. At last, you've given `ids` to individual datepickers, so you can either use the jQuery methods on `ids` or on `class`.

[Codepen - Working Demo](https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/orzrMw)

Comment: can you share the CDN you have used to achieve this?

Comment: It's on home page of the doc website